# how i share state in this case for stateobjec

Tags: ios, swift

I have an error about SwiftUI stage managment. I integrating a chat platform to my indie project. But it does not appear on the screen when new messages are sent. We can only see it after leaving the page and re-entering.

**Page view init codes:**

```
@StateObject var chatVm : ChatViewModel
@EnvironmentObject var auth: AuthService
@State var message: String = ""
let toUser: User?
let fromUser : User?


init(fromUser: User? , toUser: User?){
    self.toUser = toUser
    self.fromUser = fromUser
    _chatVm = StateObject<ChatViewModel>(wrappedValue: ChatViewModel(fromUser: fromUser!, toUser: toUser!))
}
```

**View Model init codes**

```
@Published var messages: [Message] = [Message]()
@Published var tmpMessages: [Message] = [Message]()

@Published var lastMessageId: String = ""
var toUser: User?
var fromUser : User?
var db = Firestore.firestore()


init(fromUser: User, toUser: User){
        self.toUser = toUser
        self.fromUser = fromUser
        print("chat model okundu")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.getMessages()
    }
}
```

**A part of getMessages()**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            if let id = self.tmpMessages.last?.id {
                self.lastMessageId = id
            }
            self.tmpMessages.sort { $0.timestamp < $1.timestamp}
            self.messages = self.tmpMessages
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you are only calling `getMessages` when the view model inits. When else are you calling it? You really should provide a minimal reproducible example so that those trying to help you are able to do so. Leaving out information makes it harder than it needs to be.

Comment: yes, I called getmessages once. but since it is a "stateobject" shouldn't it be updated automatically when new messages are added? If I call the getmessages function on the submit of the textfield, the same message appears on the screen more than once. i dont understand completly

Comment: When are new messages added? How is that happening? There isn’t enough information in your question to determine what is happening. As I said in my previous comment you need to include a minimum reproducible example showing what happens. Including snippets of code isn’t really enough. A useable example is really needed.